# JAVA AES 256 Decrypt 32bytes

Tags: java

I'm trying to decrypt with AES some data.,i was told that encryption is a 32-byte method,i get error message is Input length not multiple of 16 bytes,so i will continue to try

add

I am reading the sample API file, I think I should be wrong with this hextoByte method

```
hashKey :Xgmz5mMUm7JdpPI7mRXIITSNjPEUtV7f
hashIv :nxKLik2dMNPUqIJy
```

this is encrypt value :

```
   MerchantID=MS15295340&RespondType=JSON&TimeStamp=1485232229&Version=1.4&MerchantOrderNo=S_1485232288&Amt=40&ItemDesc=UnitTest
```

encrypt answer is :

```
fb7a19d840c9877d26d961f6a906602439260588e0e9db45cdc0d4d69a3b97fe22e00fda051ee90c7e987e62a717d409a45e4c04893caa90b31f86dc32929debb391145325f07068854efb5977e9aed0b684e7b0a1cb45a764bad9f4d9ab32cb1f634c66e315054b2d3589a1d9fc0ad3dfdb8dad102df281c306c25972047d4e
```

main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hashKey = "Xgmz5mMUm7JdpPI7mRXIITSNjPEUtV7f";
        String hashIv = "nxKLik2dMNPUqIJy";
        String value = "MerchantID=MS15295340&RespondType=JSON&TimeStamp=1485232229&Version=1.4&MerchantOrderNo=S_12345667822&Amt=40&ItemDesc=UnitTest";
        Map<String, Object> map = encryptSpgateway(hashKey, hashIv, value);
        System.out.println(map);

        String decrypt = decryptSpgateway(hashKey, hashIv,
                "fb7a19d840c9877d26d961f6a906602439260588e0e9db45cdc0d4d69a3b97fe22e00fda051ee90c7e987e62a717d409a45e4c04893caa90b31f86dc32929debb391145325f07068854efb5977e9aed065bafa1c91f243f0fc1efac2f0d8db2a16276764914eaf38b9e61ae1e12731e9461d493860ace4b89a3d49203c1745dd");
        System.out.println(decrypt);
    }
```

this encrypt code

```
public static Map<String, Object> encrypt(String hashKey, String hashIv, String value) {
        Map<String, Object> encryMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(hashKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(hashIv.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(addPKCS7Padding(value.getBytes("UTF-8"), 32));
            String encryResult = bytesToHex(encrypted).toLowerCase();
            encryMap.put("encry", encryResult);
            return encryMap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static byte[] addPKCS7Padding(byte[] data, int iBlockSize) {
        int iLength = data.length;
        byte cPadding = (byte) (iBlockSize - (iLength % iBlockSize));
        byte[] output = new byte[iLength + cPadding];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, output, 0, iLength);
        for (int i = iLength; i < output.length; i++)
            output[i] = (byte) cPadding;
        return output;
    }

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(bytes[i] & 0xFF);
            if (hex.length() == 1) {
                hex = '0' + hex;
            }
            sb.append(hex);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

this is my decrypt Code

```
public static String decrypt(String hashKey, String hashIv, String value) {
        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(hashKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(hashIv.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(HexToBytes(value)));
        byte[] unpadded = RemovePKCS7Padding(decrypted);
        return new String(unpadded, "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static byte[] RemovePKCS7Padding(byte[] data) {
        int ilength = data[data.length - 1];
        byte[] output = new byte[data.length - ilength];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, output, 0, output.length);
        return output;
    }

    public static byte[] HexToBytes(String value) {
    value = value.toUpperCase();
    int length = value.length() / 2;
    char[] hexChars = value.toCharArray();
    byte[] b = new byte[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int pos = i * 2;
        b[i] = (byte) (charToByte(hexChars[pos]) << 4 | charToByte(hexChars[pos + 1]));
    }
    return b;
}

public static byte charToByte(char c) {
    return (byte) "0123456789ABCDEF".indexOf(c);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete errorTrace.

Comment: @Abhishek you say this error message IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 16 bytes? i just get this no other

Comment: Can you check, if you have provided the correct key, as I'm getting error `java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size`

Comment: @Abhishek this key is correct ,i also use this set of keys for encryption,so i am also confused

Comment: @Abhishek If you get an illegal key size exception, then you may be using the limited strength cryptogrpahy jurisdiction policy.

Comment: @JulyMan did my answer help you?

Comment: @Abhishek i think you are right ,Thank you, my friend

Comment: @xtratic i am understanding where I am wrong. i try later,thanks

Comment: If it answered your question then please accept it as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you use `AES/CBC/NoPadding` and then add padding manually? Why not just use `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`, which will take care of padding for you? BTW your padding in NOT PKCS7, look more like zero padding.

Comment: @rustyx Because API file example,  need a custom padding provided , i can change  AES/CBC/NoPadding to AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding  is no doubt,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. Your cipher was in ENCRYPT_MODE when you where trying to decrypt
2. You shouldn't remove the padding from the encrypted string, you can remove it from the decrypted string if you like.

Change your decrypt method to this:

```
public static String decrypt(String hashKey, String hashIv, String value) {
    try {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(hashKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(hashIv.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(HexToBytes(value));
        byte[] unpadded = removePKCS7Padding(decrypted);
        return new String(unpadded, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: i can't change addPKCS7Padding method ,this method used elsewhere,and do not understand no need HexToBytes method,forgive me, my degree is not very good

Comment: Your first two points -- mode=decrypt and unpad after decrypting -- are correct, but OPs ciphertext is hex not base64, and your changed padding is quite wrong: it's NOT what PKCS7 requires. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2315#section-10.3 .

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you, you're right that the padding change was incorrect. OP has `cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(HexToBytes(value)));` which threw me off; As you note, it should instead be purely `cipher.doFinal(HexToBytes(value));`